# Working with TCameraComponent

Tags: delphi, firemonkey, delphi-10-seattle

I am trying to resize a captured `TCameraComponent` image using the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.GetImage;
begin
  imagec.SampleBufferToBitmap(img.Bitmap, True);

  with resizedimg.Bitmap do // Resize the image to another bitmap
  begin
    SetSize(300, 160);
    if Canvas.BeginScene then
    try
      Canvas.DrawBitmap(img.Bitmap, TRectF.Create(0, 0, 300, 160), TRectF.Create(0, 0, 300, 160), 1.0);
    finally
      Canvas.EndScene;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

But, each time I turn the camera off and re-open it again, the resized image captures a zoomed part of the actual `TImage`.  Why does this behavior happen? What am I doing wrong?

The goal is to resize `img.Bitmap` to fit within 300x160 pixels.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 2nd parameter of `DrawBitmap()` should be the original size of the `img.Bitmap` that is being drawn, not the size that you are trying to resize to.

```
Canvas.DrawBitmap(img.Bitmap, TRectF.Create(0, 0, img.Bitmap.Width, img.Bitmap.Height), TRectF.Create(0, 0, 300, 160), 1.0);
```

In Berlin and later, `TBitmap` has a `BoundsF` property you can use instead.

```
Canvas.DrawBitmap(img.Bitmap, img.Bitmap.BoundsF, TRectF.Create(0, 0, 300, 160), 1.0);
```